# How to read from an Excel file columns with different number of rows?

Tags: java, jxl

I have this method which adds in an `ArrayList` named `column` an entire column from am Excel file. But i have a problem if a column is shorter( it doesn't have as many rows as others)`empty String` error appears.

```
 public initializingWorkbook( Sheet sheet,ArrayList <Double> column, int index) 
   {
     int rows = sheet.getRows();
     for(int row = 1;row < rows;row++)

        {
            String i = sheet.getCell(index, row).getContents();
            column.add(Double.parseDouble(i));
        }
   }
```

[Here is the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD2Bk.png). So first 6 columns have the same number of rows and the `test` column fewer. Cells format are on `General`.

Comment: Did you debug your code? What is `i` when the error appears? Then check your String for this, before you do the `add`.

Comment: @IQV It gives me the `Source not found: The source attachment does not contain the source for the file SheetImpl.class`  error and it makes me select the source where `jxl.jar` is, but somehow if I `Step into` it works.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your sheet with a row where the error occurs? Which value has the cell with `empty string`?

Comment: The problem is that the `test` column doesn't have as many rows as the others I think. I edited my question with sheet included.

Comment: So you have 12 rows with 7 columns and the rest with 6 columns. The error appears when index is 6 (= column G with "Test")? So the check of my answer below prevents to read the cells in the rows 13 and above. Did you try my proposal? Did the error occur nevertheless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check first, how much columns the actual row contains:

```
{
if (index < sheet.getRow(row).length) {
    String i = sheet.getCell(index, row).getContents();
    column.add(Double.parseDouble(i));
    }
}
```

`sheet.getRow(int row)` returns all cells of this row; that is an array of cells. So you can check the dimension of the returned array.

Comment: That `if` will always be true because `index` is the number of column selected and I have only `6` columns and each column has lots of rows(approximately `40000`)

Comment: According to your sample you have 6 or 7 columns.